# Drop down Item Text Change on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have tried working on this simple [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/JAwxq/3/). The dropdown group btn on selecting the value from the drop down menu must change its text to the selected value.But it doesn't change the text from the javascript code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var d=new Date(); 
var year = ["2013","2014"];
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];




for(i=0; i<monthNames.length; i++){

    $("#dd1").append("<li><a href=''>"+monthNames[i]+"</a></li>");
$("#dd2").append("<li><a href=''>"+monthNames[i]+"</a></li>");
}
});
```

and the corresponding HTML code is given below:

```
   <div class="well carousel-search hidden-phone">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a id = 'test1'class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Choose Month 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id = "dd1" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a  id = 'test'  class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Choose Month 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id = "dd2" class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a couple problems... First. You need to anchor the links youre adding dynmically. Thats simply done with `$("#dd1").append("<li><a href='#'>..."`. Without this I was getting an error in the fiddle.

Second. You need to make sure you select the a tag with your jquery. Then you can just pull the text and you can also use jQuery again to set the text of the test1 div. See below

```
$("#dd1 li a").click(function () {
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $("#test1").text(selText);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JAwxq/4/

Answer (score 1):

Going off your JS Fiddle, id do this:

change

```
$("#dd1").click(function(){
var selText = $(this).text();
var objSelect = document.getElementById("test1");
objSelect.text = selText;
});
```

to

```
$("#dd1 li a").click(function(){
  $('#test1').text($(this).text());
});
```